# Compare conservation rates of a variable in two-factor experiment

Tags: r, data-visualization, standard-error

This is probably a very simple question for anyone using R, but I am fairly new to it (and stats in general) and I can't figure this simple computation out.

I have 3 varieties of plants (A, B, C) tested with 2 different nutrient supplies, and the weights of the plants are measured. The data is balanced. (Here is an example of dataset: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1755762/example.csv)

I can compare the means between genotypes and treatments, with for example `bargraph.CI` from the `sciplot` package, which I like because of the automatic SE bars:

```
bargraph.CI(Genotype, Weight, Treatment, legend=T, ylab="Dry weight (g)", xlab="Genotype")
```

which would produce something like that (just to have an idea at what I am looking at):

[image]

I would then complement this with the classes from a Tukey HSD post-hoc test with `HSD.test` from the `agricolae` package (if Anova showed a Genotype×Treatment interaction):

```
int <- interaction(Genotype, Treatment)
HSD.test(aov(Weight~int), "int", group=T)
```

But **how can I compare the conservation rates between the two treatments for each genotypes?** By this I mean: compare, for each genotype, the ratio "Treatment 1 weight mean over Treatment 2 weight mean" (this would be just one bar per genotype, showing the weight conservation rate between the two treatments).

It would be great to get a graph similar to what `bargraph.CI` produces, but I don't know how to determine if the differences between those weight conservation rates are significant: would standard error bars be relevant here?

Comment: I think standard error bars are *always* relevant, it's just a question of getting the standard errors right (b/c the typical formulas don't always apply given your situation). When you don't know the right formula, one approach is to bootstrap.

Comment: For a reference on the potential for different types of error bars, see Using Confidence Intervals for Graphically Based Data Interpretation ([Masson & Loftus, 2003](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/mike/5030/articles/MassonLoftusCI.pdf)). Also pertinent, see some critiques of Dynamite plots, (see [Drummond & Vowler](http://dx.doi.org/10.1113/jphysiol.2011.205062). 2011. Show the data, don’t conceal them). Also I give many references to discussion about error bars (and examples of how to display them in ggplot2 in R) in this [post](http://goo.gl/qXjY8).

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments .
However, I am still not sure how to simply calculate the ratio between means and represent it graphically (first step before representing error bars!).